# How to collapse gaps around empty column/row/track?

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I have a grid where the first column always contains elements, but the elements of the second and the third ones are displayed conditionally.

```css
.grid {
    display: grid;
    gap: 16px;

    background-color: gray;
}

.first {
    grid-column: 1;

    height: 32px;
    width: 32px;
    background-color: red;
}

.second {
    grid-column: 2;

    height: 32px;
    width: 32px;
    background-color: green;
}

.third {
    grid-column: 3;

    height: 32px;
    width: 32px;
    background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
    <div class="first"></div>
    <div class="second"></div>
    <div class="third"></div>

    <div class="first"></div>
    <div class="third"></div>

    <div class="first"></div>
    <div class="second"></div>
</div>
```

[image]

Then I face the conditions when the all elements of the third column aren't displayed. All works fine, no problem.

```html
<div class="grid">
    <div class="first"></div>
    <div class="second"></div>

    <div class="first"></div>

    <div class="first"></div>
    <div class="second"></div>
</div>
```

[image]

But when the all elements of the **second** column aren't displayed and the third has at least one element, I get double gap.

```html
<div class="grid">
    <div class="first"></div>
    <div class="third"></div>

    <div class="first"></div>
    <div class="third"></div>

    <div class="first"></div>
    <div class="third"></div>
</div>
```

[image]

How can I avoid this double gap?

As workaroud for this specific case I can use `padding-left` and `margin-left` instead of `gap`, but I interest how it can be done with CSS grids itself, if I use `gap` rule.